# select random user or none from the data frame?

Tags: python, select, random

Say that I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'user': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                'value': [0.64, 0.93, 0, 0.43, 0.65, 0]})
df
```

I used sample() to select one row (user) randomly

```
df1 =df.sample()
df1
```

How could I randomly select one user or no user? I mean the expected output could be one user (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6) then (print user id) or no user id is returned (print no user is selected)?

for example:
if user 1 is selected randomly

```
print(user 1 is selected)
```

if no user is selected

```
print(no user is selected)
```

Comment: But why would no user be selected? If the real data you have has a valid user for every row, using .sample will always return one user. Or does the real data has entries for which a user is invalid (e.g. None in user column)?

Comment: @Lfppfs The data has a valid user for every row but I want it for technical reasons because sometimes no user is selected.

Comment: You could always have `None` as an element in the users list and add a condition to handle it

Comment: @Sid this could be work, could you give an example based on my code

Comment: Can't you just get a random number ranging from 0 to the size of your user list + 1, and if + 1, then None ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Sid's answer, add a row with None and perform the sampling:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'user': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                'value': [0.64, 0.93, 0, 0.43, 0.65, 0]})
df = pd.\
    concat([
        df,
        pd.DataFrame({'user': [None], 'value': [None]})
    ])

sample = df.sample(1)["user"].iloc[0]
if sample is None:
    print("no user is selected")
else:
    print(f"user {sample} is selected")
```